# Fixing the Y axis movement of a Ping Pong Program

Tags: java, pong

I'm having trouble with a Ping Pong program we're supposed to make for my java class. We were giving the documents and it needs editing. its and automatic ping pong game so it does require any input, it's all by chance by the computer. I just need the paddle to go up and down. I've gotten it to move and everything.

My problem here is the Y range is from 20 - 465. It counts down from 465 to 20, then instead of counting up from 20 to 465, it just jumps all the way up to 465 again and counts down from 20, thereby making the pad disappeared from the bottom to the top pretty fast. I'm going to attach the project in case anyone wants to check it out for me.

I'm not just looking for someone to help me figure out why its jumping and not counting up.
here's the code if the problem can be figure out from it alone.
I'm working with the edgeCheck and Update methods.

```
import java.awt.Point;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
public class CharlesPaddle extends Paddle {
    /************************************************** ***************/
    public CharlesPaddle(int _x) {
        super(_x);
        ImageIcon iiPaddle = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("paddle.png"));
        paddleImage = iiPaddle.getImage();
    } //end CharlesPaddle
    /************************************************** ***************/
    public void update() {
        if (edgeCheck() == false)
            do {
                paddleLocation.y -= 1;
                System.out.println(paddleLocation.y);
            }
            while (paddleLocation.y >= 21);
        else if (edgeCheck() == true)
            do {
                paddleLocation.y += 1;
            }
            while (paddleLocation.y <= 465);

    } //end update

    /************************************************** ***************/
    public void init() {
        paddleLocation = new Point();
        paddleVector = new Point();
        paddleVector.x = 0;
        paddleVector.y = speed;
        paddleLocation.x = xLocation;
        paddleLocation.y = 200;
    } //End init
    /************************************************** ***************/
    public boolean edgeCheck()
    {

        boolean check = false;
        if (paddleLocation.y >= 465)
            check = false;
        else if (paddleLocation.y <= 20)
            check = true;
        return check;

    } // End edgeCheck
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense. Why do you have a do/while loop when you can just set `paddleLocation = 20`? It does the same thing. Same with the one below it. What is `edgeCheck()` supposed to do? It only returns true if it's on the right edge...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm not just looking for someone to help me figure out why its jumping and not counting up.

Well, it would be too hard for me to figure out anyway.

You have two options as I see it

**Sin function (better)**

If your top is 465, and your bottom is 20, then your amplitude should be (465 - 20) / 2, or 222.5. Your y-intersect should be your amplitude plus the bottom, so 242.5. Declare a `double t`, and do this in your update:

```
public void update() {
    paddleLocation.y = (int)((222.5) * Math.sin(t) + (242.5))
    t += Math.PI * .01; // This number is arbitrary

}
```

**Fix your code (I probably missed something, but try it out)**

Your code is really sloppy and unintuitive, sorry. But I'll try my best to direct you.

I think the problem is that you have an unnecessary loop inside of your `update` method. This is causing the "jump". The `update` method should be called frequently, and you're just acting on one variable here, so you don't need the loop. Instead, try this:

```
import java.awt.Point;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
public class CharlesPaddle extends Paddle {
    /************************************************** ***************/
    public CharlesPaddle(int _x) {
        super(_x);
        ImageIcon iiPaddle = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("paddle.png"));
        paddleImage = iiPaddle.getImage();
    } 
    /************************************************** ***************/
   public void update() {
        goingUp = updateDirection(goingUp);
        if (goingUp)
            paddleLocation.y += 1;
        else
            paddleLocation.y -= 1;

        System.out.println("y position: " + paddleLocation.y);
    }

    /************************************************** ***************/
    public void init() {
        paddleLocation = new Point();
        paddleVector = new Point();
        paddleVector.x = 0;
        paddleVector.y = speed;
        paddleLocation.x = xLocation;
        paddleLocation.y = 200;
    } 
    /************************************************** ***************/
    public boolean updateDirection(boolean goingUp)    // This name makes more sense
    {
        if (goingUp && paddleLocation.y >= 465)      // It's just peaked,
            return false;                            // so return false (going down)
        else if (!goingUp && paddleLocation.y <= 20) // It's just gone to the bottom,
            return true;                             // so return true (going up)
        else                                         // It's somewhere in between,
            return goingUp;                          // so don't change anything!             
    }
}
```

Either of those should work.

I renamed your methods and variables because they didn't make sense. I also removed some of your redundant commenting.

In your main method, you should then call this update() repeatedly with either a for or while loop. You can also print out the paddleLocation in your update method, or do whatever you want with it.

Comment: This is the code i started out with originally. My problem persists when The paddle gets to the height of the location.y 465, it goes back down to 464 and it becomes true again then goes up to 465, and its a constant cycle. 

465, 464, 465, 464, 465. Any idea what my next step should be? 
thanks again, I implemented the changes you suggested.

Comment: Hey, sorry about that. I didn't even check my own code to work! I've identified the problem, and this will fix it if you name the variables correctly.

Comment: By "this will fix it", I mean I edited my answer in both the `update` and `updateDirection` methods

Comment: I added what you had changed but the problems still there. It gets stuck at the top. I can see it changing directions but not constant. still the 465,464,465 issue. The original public boolean goingUP() method, is it to be changed to update direction or left alone as it was?

Comment: I can't recreate the issue, so can you send me all your source code? Use this: https://gist.github.com/

Comment: Alright, There are also 3 pictures that I'm not sure how to add to the Gist. I'm pretty sure it's needed to run the program.

Comment: It's fine, I can replace them or disuse them easily

Comment: Alright here it is. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/81484dc9b232eda87bd1 
I really appreciate this btw.

Comment: Looks like you didn't implement my edited version. Take another look at my answer. I don't see it in the code you sent me.

Comment: Your application works for me. I had to clean up a little bit [in this class](https://gist.github.com/) I'm not sure how to control it... but after a while, it looks like something else in another class is locking the ball in place, and the update method isn't even being called.

Comment: Holy hell! Its working! When I implemented your edited version there were some red lines and i tried to fix it on my own. Probably tweaked with the final product. But thanks alot!

Comment: Hey! I wasnt sure how to get a hold of you but you really helped me out last time. I got a small problem. Do you mind looking at it?

Comment: Because the way this website works, you're going to have to make a new question, and then I'll answer it there if I can

Comment: Its already up but hasn't gotten much attention. Thanks for taking the time to look at it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21491288/counting-wins-in-a-ping-pong-game/21491381?noredirect=1#comment32441435_21491381