# Counting Wins in a Ping Pong game

Tags: java, methods, pong

> Create a method in Scores.java that takes 2 arguments: player1Scores and player2Scores.  The method should print out the number of games player1 won and the number of games player2 won.

This is the last part to an assignment given by our teacher and I can't figure out where to start. I was thinking a simple compare each win but thats not provided by the Player1Score. It only stores the current score of the game thats going on. I need to be able to calculate all the games that have happened. Any idea how i could add this to my code? Here is a snippet of the program I'm working on so far.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Scores {

public static void main (String args[]) 

{


}
static String allScoresFilename = "allscores.txt";

static String lastScoreFilename = "lastscores.txt";

public boolean writeScores(int player1Score, int player2Score) throws IOException {

PrintWriter scores = new PrintWriter (new File ("Score.txt"));

    scores.println("Player 1 \t Player 2 \n " +player1Score+"\t\t\t " +player2Score);

PrintWriter scores1 = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Scores Append", true)));

    scores1.println("Player One:"+player1Score+"\tPlayer Two:"+player2Score);

    scores1.close();

    scores.close();

    return true;

}//End writeScores

public boolean appendScores(int player1Score, int player2Score) throws IOException{

    return true;

}//End appendScores

public void readScores() throws FileNotFoundException

{

    File scores = new File ("Scores Append");

    Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner (scores);

    fileScanner.useDelimiter("[\t|,|\n|\r|:]+");

    String players, player1;

    int numbers, i=0;

    int []p1= new int[10];

    int []p2= new int[10];

    while (fileScanner.hasNext())
    {

        players = fileScanner.next();

        p1[i] = fileScanner.nextInt();

        player1 = fileScanner.next();

        p2[i] = fileScanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println ("p1 is currently "+ p1[i]);

        System.out.println ("p2 is currently "+ p2[i]);

        i++;
    }

}//End readScores

public boolean wins(int player1Score, int player2Score) throws IOException

{

    return true;

}//End wins
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the declaration for these arrays outside of `readScores()` and put it at the top of your class so that you can invoke `wins` with them.

```
int []p1= new int[10];

int []p2= new int[10];
```

Change the signature of `wins` to this:

```
public void wins(int []player1Scores, int []player2Scores)
{
    int player1Wins = 0;
    int player2Wins = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        (player1Scores > player2Scores) ? player1Wins++ : player2Wins++;

    System.out.printf("Player 1 wins: %-10i Player 2 wins %-10i", player1Wins, player2Wins);
}//End wins
```

I won't be replying to any comments on this because I'm super busy tonight, but good luck Charles.

Comment: Thanks so much. It definately got me closer!

Answer (score 0):

You already have a `readScores` function which reads in a list of the player 1 and player 2 scores.  Based on that, you can easily go through those Arrays and determine which player won each game.

Comment: Any chance how i should go about that? Since its a void statement i cant return any information from it right?

Comment: You could do a couple of things.  One would be to modify the class so that it "remembers" the scores instead of just throwing them away at the end of the function.  A private data member or two within your `Scores` class might be the way to do that.

Comment: Note too, that the assignment says that inputs are `player1Scores` (plural) and `player2Scores` (plural).  This gives a hint that passing single scores is not what you are expected to be doing there.

Comment: Would changing it to int and returning p1[i] & p2[i] be sufficient? im thinking that or calling the whole  readScores method in  the wins method then taking then doing a compare and contrast of the scores in there. Is that possible?

Comment: Consider changing your method from `public boolean wins(int player1Score, int player2Score) throws IOException` to `public void printWins(int player1Scores[], int player2Scores[]) throws IOException` and consider how one might write that method and how one might call it.

Comment: Thank you. Would what i said about p1[i] & p2[i] be going the the right direction also?